# mdev racing when creating and deleting device node

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, udev, busybox

Recently, I used to `mdev` to replace `udev`. Comparing to `udevd`, `mdev` really save much memory usage. The configuration is as follow:

- in `/etc/mdev.conf`, if the device matched against `sd[a-z][0-9]`, the script `usbmount_wrapper` will be called for both "after creating and before removing device"

  sd[a-z][0-9] 0:0 660 */usbmount_wrapper
- in `usbmount_wrapper`, we called the `usbmount` utility of debian.

This configuration works fine for hotplug events (nodes under `/dev` are created and partitions are mounted correctly on devices plugged in, partitions are unmounted and device nodes are removed on device unplugged).

Issue happened when we tried to format the disk with `fdisk` tool. By dumping the hotplug event, the event sequence is :removing all old partition -> adding all new created partition. If we do a `ls /dev/sd*` right after `fdisk`, we can see new device nodes for these new partitions, after a few seconds, these partitions are removed. We can conclude that there is race condition in `mdev`, the device nodes are first created and then removed, this is contrary the sequence of hotplug events. I also tried to create `/dev/mdev.seq` but it does not solve the issue. The `mdev` version is from `busybox` **1.17**

If anyone has experimented with `mdev` and encountered the same issue, please give some advice. Appreciate your helps and thanks in advanced.

Comment: The root cause of the issue is that the usbmount script takes too much time to complete. 2 seconds blocking for next sequence number in /dev/mdev.seq is too short. We can change the blocking interval to 10 seconds in mdev.c file (included in busybox source code). This should solve the race condition. Thank everyone for your attention

Comment: Thanks! I faced the same problem, too, where just changing the boot flag on one partition caused the partition nodes to be deleted. (It should’ve been remove, then add; but due to the race condition it wound up being add, then remove.) I didn’t try your suggested fix yet; instead I just relabelled the drive (`echo "label: dos" | sfdisk /dev/sda`), waited a moment for the partition nodes to be deleted, then recreated the partitions the way I needed them to be.